# Remove EditText´s border

Tags: android

How can I quit the border to the EditText and show border in a color when I click to write in this EditText? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
<EditText  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="@null"
//Or
android:background="#00000000"
//Or
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

**EDIT**

```
   editext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            editext.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
        }

    });
```

Or

```
   editext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            editext.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: With the code you have tell to me the Edit text looks like the image of the left that I have put. But when I click in the Edit Text to write the border not appear, I want that when I click in the Edit text a red border appear like the image of the right. Thanks

Comment: @user3383415 Is that border in drawable folder. I edited Check it.

Comment: @user3383415 You can see it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

define edittext like below:

```
 <EditText  
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:background="@null"
    />
```

on clicking at edit text set a background drawable in edittext, see below

```
editext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {

        editext.setBackground(R.drawable.border);
        return true;
    }

});
```

define border drawable like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>    

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/red"/>

    <padding android:left="5dp"
             android:top="5dp"
             android:right="5dp"
             android:bottom="5dp"
             /> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="3dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="3dp" android:topRightRadius="3dp"/> 
</shape>
```

you can remove padding and borders element from drawable according to your requirement.